# Rails Mailgun::CommunicationError 403 only on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

I am trying to integrate mailgun in my rails application and it works fine, sends emails without any problem on development environment but it crashes on production server.

`initializers/mailgun.rb`

```rb
Mailgun.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']
end
```

`environments/production.rb`

```rb
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun
  config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
    api_key: ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY'],
    domain: 'mysite.com',
    api_host: 'api.eu.mailgun.net'
  }
```

What can be the cause of this problem? I get 500 error page and in the `production.log` file all I see is this:  `Mailgun::CommunicationError (403 Forbidden: Forbidden):`
I am using this gem: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby

Comment: Well are you sure on production ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY'] has the right value?

Comment: In a rails console on my server I say ENV["MAILGUN_API_KEY"] and it gives me exactly the same string as mailgun website api_key. So, yes it is the same.